# When using scalatest with mockito, scalatest throws strange exception

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest, scala-generics

I need help with scalatest and mockito. I want to write test for a simple method with generic:

```
trait RestClient {
  def put[T: Marshaller](url: String, data: T, query: Option[Map[String, String]] = None) : Future[HttpResponse]
}
```

my test class:

```
class MySpec extends ... with MockitoSugar .... {
  ...
  val restClient = mock[RestClient]
  ...
  "Some class" must {
    "handle exception and print it" in {
      when(restClient.put(anyString(), argThat(new SomeMatcher()), any[Option[Map[String, String]])).thenReturn(Future.failed(new Exception("Some exception")))
      ... 
    }
  }
}
```

when I run test, it throws following exception:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

**So, why it asks 4 matchers, if my method has only 3 parameters? Is it because of generic?**

versions:

- scala 2.11.7
- scalatest 2.2.4
- mockito 1.10.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the following notation

```
def put[T: Marshaller](a: A, b: B, c: C)
```

is equivalent to

```
def put[T](a: A, b: B, c: C)(implicit m: Marshaller[T])
```

So you need to pass in a matcher for the marshaller:

```
put(anyA, anyB, anyC)(any[Marshaller[T]])
```